# Dynamically add jQuery event handlers to dynamic HTML

Tags: jquery

I have a div section that I'm dynamically populating via jQuery ajax:

```
$('#treeview').append(data.d);
```

Where data is a bunch of nested divs with different ids.

I also have some jQuery code that makes the divs into a treeview, with a +/- expand/collapse and dynamic data population:

```
 $('div.tree div:has(div)').addClass('parent'); // Requires jQuery 1.2!
    $('div.tree div').click(function() {
        var o = $(this);
        o.children('div').toggle();
        o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
        BindGridView($(this).attr('id'));
        return false;
    });
```

The issue is when I paste the divs into the main treeview div all is well.
When I dynamically create the exact same text, yes I've compared it, the expand/collapse & dynamic data population doesn't work; however I can see my correct div layout on my page.

I'm guessing that I need to add the click event & addClass when I'm doing the

$('#treeview').append(data.d);

But I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding elements to the DOM, then existing event handlers bound to a selector will not work (such as `click`).

You need to use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function in order to have events from newly created DOM elements captured.

---

It should be noted ([as it was in the comments by Zach L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786045/dynamically-add-jquery-event-handlers-to-dynamic-html/4786070#comment12239483_4786070)) that as of [jQuery 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) `live` has been deprecated in favor of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  The general advice is the same (tracking dynamic elements), just the mechanism (`on` vs `live`) has changed.

Comment: something like $(#treeview).live("click", function(){
     var o = $(this);
        o.children('div').toggle();
        o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
        BindGridView($(this).attr('id'));
        return false;
});

Comment: @mike: What about the `addClass`?  It doesn't have an impact, the selectors inside the function will work fine (looking for the parent class, I assume).  The `live` call should work, but it's a little hard to tell from the comments. =)

Comment: @mike you can't dynamically add the class, but you can do something like this `$(data.d).addClass('parent').appendTo('#treeview')`

Comment: @Yads, it seems your addClass changes all my div's ids to treeview, which messes things up

Comment: @casperOne, your live suggestion seem to have worked but until I can dynamically addClass the whole thing doesn't work

Comment: @Yads, I need all my divs within the treeview div to addClass('parent') not just treeview

Comment: @mike, then just rerun `$('div.tree div:has(div)').addClass('parent');` after your `$('#treeview').append(data.d);` call

Comment: @Yads, nope, not doing it. Everything goes blank

Comment: $('div.tree div').live not  $('#treeview').live, now all works

Comment: No longer correct - `live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 - use `on()`

Answer (score 4):

`live()` is deprecated.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind event handlers to dynamic elements. In most cases, `delegate()` will be the most efficient route, unless you cannot predict where the dynamic elements will exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Creating dynamic clickable objects had me foxed for some time too.
I couldn’t get the delegate() function to work either.
Eventually I found this example
http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/03/jqueryui-adding-removing-buttons-dynamically-from-a-jqueryui-dialog

and modified it to

`var buttonClear = $('#formResult').parent().find('#formMessage');`
`buttonClear.append("<input type='button' value='Clear message' id='clear'>");`

`$("#clear").click(function() {`
    // do button click action here
`});`

The formResult is a form id already on the page and the formMessage is a dynamically added message displayed after the form is submitted.
The script adds a button to the end of the form to clear the message.