# How to dynamically add click event for div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm loading div dynamically and binding the click event for the div using

`$(jq(userData.email)).live('click', function()
    {
        alert('hello from binded function call');
    });`

Here i'm using emailid (a@b.com) as div id. I'm using jq method for parsing the id. After executing, it shows 'Unrecognized expression': #a@b.com

This is the jq method, I'm using to parse

```
function jq( myid ) 
{
    return "#" + myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1" );
}
```

Comment: FYI you can't use an @ symbol in an ID

Comment: Aren't you missing a hashtag on `$(jq(userData.email)).live`? Also, `live()` has been deprecated. Try using `on()` instead.

Comment: Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786045/dynamically-add-jquery-event-handlers-to-dynamic-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to escape special characters:

```
$("#abc\\@abc").doSomething();
```

Have a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

[Please also notice that `.live()` is deprecated (and removed in jQuery >= 1.9)](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: I checked this. It removes the 'Unrecognized expression' error. But i can't get the click event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Z94z/ It's working for me without problems. Please notice that `live` is deprecated and removed in jQuery >= 1.9.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u87dH/10/ Here i'm loading the div dynamically and its not working

Answer (score 1):

> a@b.com is not a valid ID .
>
> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

see the below question 
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)